# So how dangerous is Parse client-enabled push notification?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I've successfully figured out Parse client-enabled push notifications.  There are lots of easy to understand tutorials on this topic, and the relevant docs are clear.

But I know that Parse says client-enabled push notifications are dangerous.  I know we're supposed to use Cloud Code, but that seems like a pretty steep learning curve.  It's been a disaster so far.

My question:  Just how dangerous is the easy, client-enabled way?  What is the worst case scenario if my app doesn't involve any private information like addresses, phone numbers, monetary accounts, etc.  And is client-enabled push notification dangerous for users or dangerous for me?

Thanks,

Eli

Comment: Are you referring to this post? http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/

Comment: Yes.  It's a good post, but I'm having a lot of trouble at the "parse deploy" part.  I ended up with a ruined project that's missing a pbxproject file.  I'm frustrated and was looking for an easier way.  I'll start over with Cloud Code in the morning.